# insertAdjacentHTML inserts <div /> when it should not

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have a main DIV where I would like to insert different DIVs via PHP.

Very simplified my HTML looks like:

```
<div id="mainDiv">
   <div id="invoice1">
      ....
   </div>

   <div id="invoice2">
      ....
   </div>

   <div id="invoice3">
      ....
   </div>
</div>
```

The user can then interact by clicking on buttons (ajax) and fx. the div with "invoice2" needs to be given new HTML (cleared out and having inserted the new HTML).

I can do this by using innerHTML but gets very slow with 100's of divs (invoices) and the coding is not nicely done.

To improve this I tried with insertAdjacentHTML but I cannot get it to make HTML like:

```
<div id="invoice1">
```

insertAdjacentHTML inserts it as

```
<div id="invoice1"></div>
```

And the ending

```
</div>
```

is stripped away (making the page look wrong).

So how can I do this in a smart way?

Comment: You cannot do just `<div>`...

Comment: The browser will automatically close the tags for you. i don't think you can't leave the `dom` open.

Comment: @JensKirk What are you actually trying to do..? If performance the problem then share the code, but that's better suited for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) i guess.

Comment: Perhaps I have to rewrite my code so I do not need open DOM objects :-)